# Лексические нормы в русском языке

Tags: лексика, предлоги

Возник вопрос насчет лексики. Как правильно *иммунитет к или от инфекции*? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ответ исправлен

ИММУНИТЕТ, м.  [от лат. immunitas (immunitatis) - освобождение **от чего-л.**]  Спец. 1. **Невосприимчивость** организма к каким-л. инфекционным заболеваниям или яду. Врождённый, естественный и. Приобретённый и. И. к кори. Выработать и. **к чему-л. или против чего-л.** (об устойчивой реакции **против инфекции)**. // Способность противостоять чему-л. Приобрести и. против жизненных трудностей.

В словаре указаны варианты с предлогами **К и ПРОТИВ**. Иммунитет можно понимать как невосприимчивость к инфекции или устойчивость против инфекции.

Из словаря: НЕВОСПРИИМЧИВЫЙ (невосприимчив) **к чему**. Невосприимчивый к инфекционным заболеваниям организм; Невосприимчив к болезням. УСТОЙЧИВОСТЬ **к чему / против чего.** Он пытался выработать в своём организме устойчивость к болезням; Устойчивость против гнили.

**В Нацкорпусе:**

Обычно такому зараженному грозит  приступ лихорадки, после чего он выздоравливает и даже **приобретает иммунитет** **против** данного типа вируса. [Андрей Железных. А пусть не кусают... // «Знание-сила», 2012]

После иммунизации 100% привитых **выработали иммунитет к** вирусу кори  // «Вопросы вирусологии», 2003.12.01]

Любая из прививок «создает» иммунитет **от прививаемой болезни**, но ослабляет общий иммунитет. [ Наши дети: Малыши до года (форум) (2004)]

**В СМИ** используется форма "иммунитет от":  У перенесших COVID-19 в мягкой форме заметили иммунитет от коронавируса.  В Роспотребнадзоре рассказали, у кого появится иммунитет от COVID-19. В Калининградской области популяционный иммунитет от COVID-19 превысил 20%.

Comment: Поддерживаю, но всё же в вопросе спрашивали про "иммунитет от". Такое в разы реже встречается в научных публикациях и у меня вызывает сомнения. А у Вас другие "оба варианта".

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, что "оба хуже". Я бы рекомендовал ***"иммунитет против"***, хотя и тут есть серьезные возражения.

По порядку. Мне неизвестна нормирующая фиксация, да еще дело осложняется тем, что у медиков очень много профессиональных оборотов (по сути - жаргонизмов), которые нельзя рекомендовать для общелитературного употребления.

Остается только порассуждать. И вот рассуждения показывают, что "иммунитет" - это всего-навсего "способность [противостоять инфекции]". Тогда при использовании разбираемых вариантов получается "способность к инфекции" (что чудовищно по стилю) или, того хуже "способность от инфекции", что некоторый смысл имеет, но почти столь же чудовищно на слух.

"Способность против" пусть и тяжеловесно, но хотя бы однозначно толкуется.

Для сравнения: из вариантов "борьба с врагами (сорняками, помехами, болезнями)" и "борьба против врагов" второй однозначно лучше вне подчеркнуто разговорного стиля речи.